# jQuery call function from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function, methods

Is it possible to call a function by using the strings ?

(i.e) I have a variable `var target = 'next';`. Using this string I want to call the jquery method `next()` . Should i use `target + '()'` (this is bit foolish) to call `next()` ?

I know it can be done using `conditional` statements. Since it is a string got from users, but it is difficult to use conditional statements for all that.

In my jQuery plugin, users will pass the value `prev`, `siblings` etc as options, so that the respective jQuery methods will be executed.

How do I implement this ?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use the [bracket notation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1) to access the member with a string containing the identifier:

```
var target = 'next';
$("foobar")[target]();    // identical to $("foobar").next()
```

Comment: This is really useful if you know you can call method using `MyObject.call(myFunctionName, args);` Functional programming FTW. Thanks for the tip, Gumbo.

Comment: You should have accepted the solution of slightlymore, because this is not save. Especially because you don't know what your user types in. What if he makes a typo? The solution of slightlymore won't break your script.

Comment: @MarcoFranssen A `try … catch` could easily fix that.

Comment: try catching is not the way to do this. If you just check before invoking this is much better.

Comment: @MarcoFranssen In that case you should also check whether it’s actually a function, e. g. `jQuery.fn.length` is not a function.

Answer (score 16):

If you're wanting to use jQuery, the answer is quite elegant. Because jQuery is an object (which can be accessed like an array) - you can use `$("selector")[target]()`.

Examples:

```
const target = 'next';
jQuery("selector")[target]();
```

This will work if you know that you can trust the input. However, if you're not sure of this, you should check that the function exists before trying to run it otherwise you'll get an error.

```
const target = 'doesNotExist';
const fn = jQuery('selector')[target];
if (jQuery.isFunction(fn)) {
  fn[target]();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case I needed to get the value from a rel attribute and then parse it as a function, this worked for me.

```
$jq('#mainbody form').submit(function(e){
    var formcheck = $jq(this).attr('rel');
    if (typeof window[formcheck] === 'function'){
        formok = window[formcheck]();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
function maincheck(){
    alert("Checked");
    return false;
}
```

and the form

```
<div id="mainbody">
<form action="mainpage.php" method="post" rel="maincheck">
<input type="hidden" name="formaction" value="testpost">
<label>Field 1 <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?=$_POST['field1'];?>"></label><br>
<label>Field 2 <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?=$_POST['field2'];?>"></label><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
</div>
```