# Property '$.fn.toggleHeightAndOpacity' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, typeerror

I'm trying to call a variable function name as I've done many times before using similar code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326078/jquery-call-function-from-a-string) with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.toggleHeightAndOpacity = function(show) {
        $(this).stop(true,false).animate({
            opacity: (show)?'show':'hide',
            height: (show)?'show':'hide'
        },
        function(){
            $(this).css('display', (show)?'auto':'none')
        })
    };
```

...

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    if(evt.data.type = 'function'){
        var parameters;
        try{
            parameters = JSON.parse(data.parameters);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            parameters = data.parameters;
        }
        $('#'+data.id)[data.function](parameters)
    }
};
```

but I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$.fn.toggleHeightAndOpacity' of object [object Object] is not a function` even though the JSON returned from my WebSocket server is `{"function":"$.fn.toggleHeightAndOpacity","id":"container","parameters":true,"type":"function"}`.

`container` exists in my html, and jQuery is loaded.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects can be accessed with either dot or bracket notation, so these two are the same

```
object.key

object['key']
```

As jQuery selectors and methods are objects, like everything else in javascript, they to can be accessed the same way, so these two are the same

```
$('#element').fadeIn();

$('#element')['fadeIn']();
```

That means the plugin can be accessed with these two methods

```
$('#'+data.id)['toggleHeightAndOpacity'](parameters);

$('#'+data.id).toggleHeightAndOpacity(parameters);
```

So, if the data returned from the server really is

```
{"function":"$.fn.toggleHeightAndOpacity", ...
```

You're really doing

```
$('#'+data.id)['$.fn.toggleHeightAndOpacity'](parameters)
```

and that doesn't look right, it should be

```
$('#'+data.id)['toggleHeightAndOpacity'](parameters)
```

so change the serverside code to output the function name without `$.fn`.
Using `function` as a key looks a little hinky as it's a reserved keyword in javascript, so I would get in the habit of not naming keys or variables `function`

Comment: Thank you so much adeneo!  And thank-you for the tip on not using the keyword!  Would you mind also posting why I was incorrect?  I don't understand why.  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: Absolutely beautiful!  Thank-you!