# jquery trigger function based on select list

Tags: jquery, function, selectlist

I've got a pretty basic jQuery question. I'm trying to trigger an existing function depending on the option chosen from a select list.

Example HTML:

```
<select name="selectAction" id="selectAction">
  <option>Choose an action</option>
  <option value="firstFunction">First Function</option>
  <option value="secondFunction">Second Function</option>
  <option value="thirdFunction">Third Function</option>
</select>
```

The goal is to run firstFunction() if that option is selected, secondFunction() if that one is chosen, etc.

I can get the value of the select list, but not sure how to use that to execute a specific function.

So I have this, so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').on('change', '#selectAction', function(e) {
    var theValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
});
```

});

I know I could use eval() to handle this - `eval(theValue + '()');` - but I'm trying to avoid that course. I also realize I could use a series of if/else or switch/case statements, but that seems a little inelegant. Is there a way to trigger the function based on the value name itself?

TIA - Joe

Comment: Put those functions into object `{name: func, name2: func2}[nameToBeCalled]()`

Comment: Is this what you are asking about?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3326095/903014

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Create an object: `var API = {firstFunction: firstFunction, ...}`. And use it like this: `$('#selectAction').change(function(){API[$(this).val()]();})`

Comment: @Steve - I thought that might be the answer too, so I tried adding `$('html')[theValue]();` to my on() function, but the selected function didn't fire. The function is defined in a script tag in the head. Could I have the selector wrong?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko expanded on this idea in his first comment.  You need to move your function definitions into an object so that they can be executed in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object that acts as a namespace for your functions. And bind on select change.

```
$(function() {
   var API = {
     firstFunction: function(){},
     secondFunction: ...
   };

   $('#selectAction').change(function() {
      var method = API[$(this).val()];
      return method && method();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Yury, but the function doesn't run as expected. Just to make sure I understand, the value for each array element will always be `function(){}` like `firstFunction: function(){},
     secondFunction: function(){}` - is that right?

Comment: Nope. The value should be the function you want to be called. :)