# Call a jquery plugin by variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement multiple jQuery plugins for a small application.
I have the list of plugins names and the plugins.

How can I call a plugin having its name stored in a variable?

So, instead of this:

```
$("div#exercise-container").demo_plugin_for_exercise1();

$("div#exercise-container").demo_plugin_for_exercise2();
```

I want to have a

```
var plugin_name = "demo_plugin_for_exercise1";
```

and use it to call the plugin with that name.

Comment: I will have a list of exercise types - and a plugin for each one. The details about each plugin will be stored in json format. Then when I choose an exercise I will know the plugin name to be used... that plugin_name variable. Yes, I can just say if plugin_name == "something" then call something(), but I think there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

It's working like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326078/jquery-call-function-from-a-string):

```
$("div#exercise-container")[plugin_name]();
```